# Why static variable can not be accessed by this keyword in static method if we pass static method in any route's controller(NODEJS)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, controller, static

We can access static variables in static method by using 'this' keyword but this statement does not work if we pass that static method in any route. Keyword 'this' has refrence to class but its value is undefined. How?

Actucal code is big, I have given only problematic code if you want you can run it.

Router code :-

```
import UserController from './user-controller';
router.post('/register', UserController.register);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Controller Code :-

```
 static someString = 'myString';

 static register() {
   console.log(this.someString);
 }
}

export default UserController;
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Error :-

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someString')
  at register (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/modules/user/user-controller.ts:5:22)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
  at Function.joiValidation (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/utils/validator.ts:41:7)
  at /home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/modules/user/user-validator.ts:11:22
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at /home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/modules/user/user-validator.ts:8:71
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at __awaiter (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/modules/user/user-validator.ts:4:12)
  at register (/home/user/Desktop/TS-Pro/src/modules/user/user-validator.ts:18:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general Object Oriented stuff:

- A **Class** is a blueprint. Example: `Vehicle`
- An **Object** is a specific item created using that blueprint. Example: `car` (of type `Vehicle`)
- Keywords like `this`/`me`/`self` are used to refer to an instance of an **Object** from within the same object. I want to emphasize, that an instance of an object means a specific `car` object and **not** the `Vehicle` class.
- Keyword `static` marks an attribute/method as being Class-level (i.e. you can call it without creating an object). e.g. `Vehicle.Accelerate` and not `car.accelerate`.
- Keyword `static` ALSO makes that attribute global. i.e. you can change it in 1 object and it will change for all objects, because it's actually sitting in central blueprint, and not a specific object. (not relevant to your question, but it's the next mistake people make)

**The short version:** static methods only work with static methods/variables. Instance methods (i.e. methods without `static`) can access all methods/variables. (Ignoring public/private visibility)

In most high level languages `this` is inaccessible in *static context* and your code would cause a syntax error, but JavaScript doesn't many of the limitations because any text can be almost anything (method, class, variable and more) and turn into almost anyting mid-way. It's something you have to keep in mind.

You get an error, because JS compiler doesn't check for undefined variables ahead of time and you are trying to access a different (non-static) variable by using keyword `this`.

**Finally,** To access that variable either use that variable name directly (while within the class), or use `ClassName.variableName` syntax.